Custom component coloring with Tailwind in React
I'm developing a component in React that accepts a color, a hex value as a string, and it should style various things inside my component, including states hover, before and after, focus, and in custom selectores as well.
In short, I need dynamic, arbitrary styling.
I'm well aware Tailwind does not support dynamic classes very well, but just so you know, if it did, some of my classes would look like:
before:border-t-[${color}]
hover:text-[${color}]
data-[state=open]:text-[${color}]
bg-[${color}]
hover:bg-[${color}]

I tried safelisting in tailwind, like this:
 safelist: [
    "dark",
    {
      pattern: /border-[^/]+$/,
      variants: [
        "dark",
        "hover",
        "focus",
        "dark:hover",
        "dark:focus",
        "before",
        "after",
        "data-[state=open]",
      ],
    },
    {
      pattern: /text-[^/]+$/,
      variants: [
        "dark",
        "hover",
        "focus",
        "dark:hover",
        "dark:focus",
        "before",
        "after",
        "data-[state=open]",
      ],
    },
    {
      pattern: /bg-[^/]+$/,
      variants: [
        "dark",
        "hover",
        "focus",
        "dark:hover",
        "dark:focus",
        "before",
        "after",
        "data-[state=open]",
      ],
    },
  ],

But it doesnt work.
A solution would be to set styles inline, instead of using Tailwind, but inline styles doesnt support selectors.
So It feels like I am at a dead end, and that this is something that should be quite easy and common, so I dont know.
So my final question is:
Is is possible to create a React component that accepts a color as a hex value and it will dynamically and arbitrarly style stuff inside this component (even using selectors, including custom ones)? If so, how?

For truly dynamic color values, you would need to use inline styles. The safelist regular expressions only work for configured values, like text-red-500. Tailwind can't compile every single color value in existence in arbitrary values – there would be a literal infinite amount.
For each of the classes you mentioned that have variants, you could use a CSS variable:
before:border-t-[${color}]
<div
  class="before:border-t-[--color]"
  style={{ '--color': color }}
>

hover:text-[${color}]
<div
  class="hover:text-[--color]"
  style={{ '--color': color }}
>

data-[state=open]:text-[${color}]
<div
  class="data-[state=open]:text-[--color]"
  style={{ '--color': color }}
>

hover:bg-[${color}]
<div
  class="hover:bg-[--color]"
  style={{ '--color': color }}
>

And then for the bg-[${color}], you'd use an inline style:
<div style={{ backgroundColor: color }}>

Though you could also use a CSS variable for this, though it feels redundant (but might make sense in your component):
<div
  class="bg-[--color]"
  style={{ '--color': color }}
>


Wow! This worked! I was struggling with this for a long time, thank you very much.
Just as an addend: for those using Typescript, you should use "style={{ ‘--color’: props.color } as React.CSSProperties}"
